# MFC: Didn't get EN_CHANGE message within derived CEdit

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I see very strange behavior of CEdit. In my derived class from CEdit control  I need to catch text change event. I do it via `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX`

```
class CSomeDerivedEdit : public CEdit
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CSomeDerivedEdit )
public:
    CSearchEditCtrl();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg BOOL OnEnChange();
...
};
```

in cpp

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CSomeDerivedEdit , CEdit)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSomeDerivedEdit , CEdit)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(EN_CHANGE, &CSomeDerivedEdit::OnEnChange) 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This control I create within some list control as child window, when I create it and pass as parent window pointer to list control everything working fine and I get EN_CHANGE events but when I pass as parent window header control of list control events didn't resive.

`m_someEdit.Create( WS_CHILDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, rcRect, this, IDC_EDIT);` here everything fine

`m_someEdit.Create( WS_CHILDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, rcRect, GetHeaderCtrl(), IDC_EDIT);` here also control create fine and I see it , but on_control_reflect didn't called when I type in edit control.

Comment: So I found again very strange solution I derive my own CHeaderCtrl class and just subclass it to list control and after that i start to get within it's child edit control EN_CHANGE event. But why it is work's this way I still don't understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX` can only work, if the receiver of the `WM_COMMAND` message is also subclassed in the MFC. If it is a pure windows control and not subclassed with the MFC the `WM_COMMAND` message is never reflected to any child.

Remember: The reflection works, because the MFC first handles a `WM_COMMAND` message from a child in the parent first and offers it back to the child control. And if not handled the `WM_COMMAND` message is handled inside the parent. Standard window controls doesn't know reflection and always handle `WM_COMMAND` messages by itself....

So if the header control is not subclassed by the MFC the reflection will not work.

Comment: So is it right solution to subclass dummy header control or is there other way to get text change event within edit control class?

Comment: My question would be: Why do you use the header as the parent.

Comment: edit will be opened on header control, it is like quick search in list control , when user start to type edit will be opened on header control with searching string. Making it child of header it will prevent any Z order issues or sibling issues , edit will be just child window of header which has clip children style.

Comment: I see no problem to use the list control itself. But sub classing the header control just to make reflection working is sufficient and ok. Document it well. This are things someone forgets fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the MSDN. When you derive the class `CEdit`, you should put the `ON_EN_CHANGE` message handler between `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP()` and `END_MESSAGE_MAP()` macros. On the other hand, the `OnEnChange` function, whose declaration is:

```
afx_msg void OnEnChange();
```

does not return a `BOOL` value. The `ON_EN_CHANGE` message handler should be like this (from MSDN):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP()
ON_EN_CHANGE(ID_OF_THIS_CONTROL,OnEnChange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Hope this will help you.